# How much of GPU RAM is used by Flash Stage3d?

Tags: flash, stage3d

Does anyone know how to measure GPU memory usage when using Stage3D in Flash?

I know there are `System.*Memory` counters, but I couldn't find GPU one.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Adobe Scout](http://gaming.adobe.com/technologies/scout/), for now it's free. As far as I know, it's the best AS profiling tool at the moment. Regarding GPU, it displays memory, draw calls count, Stage3D instructions and their result for every single frame. You can even edit your shaders and watch the result in real time. Here is [the guide](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashruntimes/articles/adobe-scout-getting-started.html).

The only problem is that you have to compile your project using the new [ASC 2](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/asc2/) compiler. If for some reason it's not possible (your project uses Flex, for example), you can enable telemetry on the compiled SWF using [SWFScoutEnabler](https://github.com/renaun/ActionScriptExamples/tree/master/SWFScoutEnabler) tool.